# asp.net gridview bind dateformat not working with update

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview, date-format

I have a GridView with a TemplateField column which shows a DateTime from a DataSource.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateStart" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("dtDateStart", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'</asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("dtDateStart", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Displaying the date in the correct format works as it should. Note that the format starts with DAY followed by MONTH.

When I switch to edit mode, change the date in the TextBox to **'31-01-2013'** and press the GridView's update-link i get an error:
*Cannot convert value of parameter 'dtDateStart' from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'* 
The error is generated by the GridView not my own code. 
It happens before the UpdateMethod of my DataSource is called.

When i type **'01-31-2012'** the data is processed correctly and the value is updated into the database.

Somehow when the date is displayed it uses format **dd-MM-yyyy** (just as I need it to)
But when it reads the new value form the TextBox it uses **MM-dd-yyyy**

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: This is just a guess, but do you have the current culture of the app set appropriately?  It would seem that the default date format for the app or the gridview is still MM-dd-yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply.
I do not know about culture settings within the website. I was assuming that proving the Bind-function with a dateformat would be sufficient.

By now I have implemented the following workaround, which is hopefully useful for others:

I have added an additional property to my class which is of type string. This property I only use for binding to the gridview.

```
// Original Date property //
public DateTime dtDateStart { get; set; }

// Additional Date property of type string // 
public string sDateStart
{
    get
    {
        return dtDateStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    set
    {
        dtDateStart = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this should be marked as the answer. But maybe others can use this as a quick workaround as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use like this

```
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateStart" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Bind("dtDateStart")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") %>'</asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
```

this weill help you.